# How to get id or name of a facebook user when it share my link

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sharer

i'm developing a page in with there are many facebook share button.

My page has url like: `http://mydomain.com/follow/show_info?id=xxxx`

what i like to do is to get info about the user that is sharing my page instead to have

```
http://mydomain.com/follow/show_info?id=xxxx&name=Name%20Surname
```

so i can put that name in my page like for example:

```
The user Name Surname has shared this page.. share that page you too!
```

Is possible? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    alert("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+ response.first_name + "ID: "+response.id);
    var img_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture"
});
```

by this you can extract current logedin user uid and name and image what you have to do when someone triger for share catch these by java script

here are some more link which will help you more

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Comment: what you are using for sharing basically

Comment: what i see that api need an app id.. how can i get it?

Comment: @GyanChandraSrivastava I'm trying to use the FB.api() inside the FB.getLoginStatus. The login status is `!unknown` but I'm getting an error in the response: `"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."` Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @aste123 did you get solution for this, because I am getting same error.

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy A possible reason is that the user may be `not_authorized`. `FB.login` can be used to ask them to authorize your app. Then you can access the user information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194011/error-in-the-response-from-facebook-graph-api