# Error in the response from facebook graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code till now is this:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
        FB.init({ appId:'my app id', status:true,  cookie:true, xfbml:true});

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            if (response.status != "unknown") // makes sure the user is already logged in.
            {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                });
            }
        });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
</script>
```

The error that I'm getting in the console is `"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."`
But I have already made sure that the user is logged in as seen from the code, then where am I making a mistake?

**Update:** From the answers and the comments, it seems like the problem is that my website is not authorized although the user is logged in. 
I just want to display the user's real name on the website with a welcome message. Can I use facebook graph API for this? 
I do not want to go into authorization step since that would seem unnecessary from the user's point of view.

I'm new to programming, javascript and facebook graph api, so please forgive any mistakes I might have made.

Comment: `if (response.status != "unknown") // makes sure the user is already logged in` – no, it doesn’t; it only makes sure that the login status is not _unknown_. It might however be `not_authorized` as well.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I just want to be able to display the user's name on my website with a welcome message if they are already logged into facebook. They won't be logging into facebook through my website. Can I use graph API for this?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you make sure the user is logged in? You did not authorize the user anywhere, you only checked if he is logged in. For example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app

    }
}, {scope: 'email,public_profile'});
```

You may want to use getLoginStatus correctly too:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        //user is authorized

    } else {
        //user is not authorized

    }
});
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Thank you. I just want to be able to display the user's name on my website with a welcome message if they are already logged into facebook. They won't be logging into facebook through my website. Can I use graph API for this?

Comment: they MUST authorize your app for that. you can´t get any user information without authorization. use FB.login for that.